# How to add admob native ad to a specific place in a webview?

Tags: javascript, android, webview, admob

I am trying to add admob native ads in my Webview app(which is a news app) . Just like adding adding ads between news posts feeds. How to do that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this.

You can only show AdMob Ads outside the webview.

If you want ads inside the webview you should use [AdSense](https://www.google.com/adsense/start/) in the webpage.

Comment: Starting from GMA SDK 20.6.0, you can show ads in `WebView`. https://developers.google.com/admob/android/webview

Comment: @ocos yes you can but they must be AdSense Ads not AdMob Ads.

Comment: I read the entire guide but it's showing you have adsense approved for doing this while I am asking for admob ads

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I thought you have also a website for news.

Comment: No I have that too but I know If i copy any news articles a little bit I will get banned from AdSense